# How to convert a bmp to webp in Node js

Tags: node.js, bmp, graphicsmagick, sharp

I need to convert a bmp image to webp in Node. I am able to do that using GraphicsMagick , but for that i need to install GraphicsMagick on the underlying OS. I need to deploy this converter application using AWS Lamba so I need a library which won't require installing anything on the OS, rather ,it can be done just using the module in Node app.

I have tried Sharp as well but it is not working with bmp(works for jpeg).

Comment: One convoluted workaround can be to convert the image first to JPG with a library like [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) and then to WebP.

Comment: Thanks, it works(kind of awkward though). But if there is a library which can work with both the formats(bmp, webp), it would be great.

Comment: Indeed, it would :) How about creating it yourself, by adding the feature to one of the existing libraries?

Comment: Sure could try to do that sometime later, but I would not try that so soon as this is my first encounter with node ;).